# Filter data based on string starts with any word/character

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to filer a data of type chararray based on string matches

```
12|john|30000|New jersey
11|mathews|23445|califonia
14|steve|230000|texas
23|jack|100000|SA
30|JAMES|300000|CANADA
```

**Case 1:**

Now, I want to filter data based on names starts with 'j' for that I have tried by first loading the data into a variable in pig. Then I tried to filter it using matches keyword but this is returning all the rows.

```
selected= filter scomp by ($1 MATCHES '.* j *.');
```

Please guide me on how I can get the desired results where I return only 2 rows.

**Case 2:**

I also want to return 3 rows (case insensitive data) john,jack and James

thanks in adv :)

Comment: please note : while posting .*j*. is getting converted to italic so provided spaces in between.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is `.*j.*`

```
selected = filter scomp by ($1 matches '.*j.*');
```

For case insensitive matches

```
selected = filter scomp by ($1 matches '(?i).*j.*');
```